# Should i use class inheritance or not?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

I have to manage dues for customers. I made a class named Due. It stores dues for two types of customers X,Y. It goes like this.

```
public abstract class Due  {

  private CustomerType customerType; //can be either X or Y 
  protected DueType dueType;
  private String dueId;
  private BigDecimal dueAmount;
  private Date dueDate;

  public Due(CustomerType type) {
     this.customerType = type;
  }

  //getters , setters goes here.
}
```

Also *DueType* are different for both X and Y. Thus I have made an interface named *DueType* and enums *XDueType*, *YDueType* implements it.

```
public interface DueType {
}

public enum XDueType implements DueType {
   A, B;
}

public enum YDueType implements DueType {
   C, D;
}
```

And i have two different classes, each specifically for X's and Y's due. Like this

```
public class XDue extends Due {

   public XDue() {
     super(CustomerType.X);
   }

   public XDueType getDueType() {
     return (XDueType) this.dueType;
   }

}

public class YDue extends Due {

   public YDue() {
     super(CustomerType.Y);
   }

   public YDueType getDueType() {
     return (YDueType) this.dueType;
   }
}
```

I have to do a lot of operations on *Due* irrespective of its type (These operations will be same for *XDue* or *YDue*).

My question is should I use inheritance here like above or not. I could have made just one class *Due* only. That could have simply done the job for me. But the former method appears like more semantically correct to me. Also, going forward *XDue*, *YDue* can become less similar. Thus I think its better to keep them separate from now. Am I correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: Why did you create an empty interface with no abstract methods?

Comment: This cannot be answered without the semantic information how XDue and YDue differ, how do they?

Comment: they have different customerType and dueType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the class needs a bit of refactoring - its a mix of inheritance and composition at the moment. I suggest going fully one-way or another

Full inheritance would move all the conditional logic into the derived clases, and have any "types" returned be stateless singletons (enums are good for this). Ideally, with a little further refactoring you can move any type depenedant code that switches on these types into the derived classes too.

```
public enum DueType { X, Y }
public enum CustomerType {X,Y}

public abstract class Due  {

  private String dueId;
  private BigDecimal dueAmount;
  private Date dueDate;

  public Due(CustomerType type) {
     this.customerType = type;
  }

  abstract DueType getDueType();
  abstract CustomerType getCustomerType();
}

public class XDue extends Due {

   @Override public DueType getDueType() {
     return DueType.X;
   }

   @Override public CustomerType getCustomerType() {
     return CustomerType.X;
   }
}
```

Or go full composition, where the Due is final and defers it's decisions to contained strategy types. Again any logic which switches on type can usually be moved into the Strategy classes.

```
public interface DueType /* Really a strategy now */ {
   void doSomeThing(Due d);
}

public interface CustomerType  /* Really a strategy now */ {
   void doSomething(Due d);
}

public final class Due {

  private String dueId;
  private BigDecimal dueAmount;
  private Date dueDate;
  DueType dueType;
  CustomerType customerType;    

  public Due(CustomerType type, DueType dueType) {
     this.customerType = type;
     this.dueType = dueType
  }
}

public class XDueType implements DueType {
...
}

public clasx XCustomerType implements CustomerType {
...
}
```

The advantage of composition over inheritance is that its cleaner to implement additional variations on DueType and Customer type that are unrelated, ie a `Due` object with `CustomerTypeA` and `DueTypeB`, without needing to create a `DueAB` class. (But if this is not possible in your situation this potential for differences is a bad thing).

Another advantage is that you can change the strategies at run-time without creating a completely new `Due` object. But again that may not be something that is needed / desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on right track. This is a king of Template pattern. 
One thing you can make use of Generics, since you have due and customer of same type:

```
public abstract class Due<T, U>  {

  private U customerType; //can be either X or Y 
  protected T dueType;
  private String dueId;
  private BigDecimal dueAmount;
  private Date dueDate;

  public Due(Utype) {
     this.customerType = type;
  }

  //getters , setters goes here.
}
```